# How to cancel the same term on both sides of equation in Maple?

Tags: maple

I tried using "simplify" but it doesn't work. For example:

`simplify(a*b=b*c) assuming b>0`

will not get a=c but return the original equation.

or even

`simplify(a*b/b) assuming b>0`

will not get a directly but return the original equation.

Could anyone help on this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `map(x -> x/b, a*b=b*c);`

```
                         a = c
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However,my original problem is in fact a long equation with some common terms (which are unknown in the beginning) on both sides, then how can Maple automatically cancel the same term on both sides of equation? For instance:

` f(a)*sin(b)*cos(c)=g(d)*sin(b)*cos(c)` 

where f(a) and g(d) are some cumbersome expression, sin(b) and cos(c) are derived automatically by some calculations (unknown in advance). how can Maple automatically cancel sin(b) and cos(c) on both sides of equation? Thanks again.

Comment: The same basic technique can be used. Once you've computed the terms to cancel, you can use `unapply` to create a function like the above to cancel things. AFAIK, there is no easy way to "cancel on both sides" (basically because it's invalid in general).